# How do I check spatial reference on all parameters during Tool Validation?

Tags: python, arcpy, coordinate-system, tool-validation

How do I check spatial reference on all parameters during Tool Validation?  Just looking for recommendations.  Here is what I have already. This must work with existing validation.

```
import arcpy
class ToolValidator(object):
  """Class for validating a tool's parameter values and controlling
  the behavior of the tool's dialog."""

  def __init__(self):
    """Setup arcpy and the list of tool parameters."""
    self.params = arcpy.GetParameterInfo()
    self.fcfield = (None, None)

  def initializeParameters(self):
    """Refine the properties of a tool's parameters.  This method is
    called when the tool is opened."""
    return

  def updateParameters(self):
    """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parmater
    has been changed."""
    if self.params[0].value and self.params[1].value:
      fc, col = str(self.params[0].value), str(self.params[1].value)
      if self.fcfield != (fc, col):
        self.fcfield = (fc, col)

        # Get the unique values of the field 'col' in the feature class 'fc'
        unique_values = [str(val) for val in
                            sorted(
                                set(
                                    row.getValue(col)
                                        for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(fc, None, None, col)
                                )
                            )
                        ]

        # Assign the unique_values list to parameters 2 and 3
        self.params[2].filter.list = unique_values
        self.params[3].filter.list = unique_values

    # Set the default values of parameters 2 and 3 to the first item in the list
    if self.params[2].value not in self.params[2].filter.list:
      self.params[2].value = self.params[2].filter.list[0]
    if self.params[3].value not in self.params[3].filter.list:
      if self.params[3].filter.list[0] != self.params[2].value:
        self.params[3].value = self.params[3].filter.list[0]
      else:
        self.params[3].value = self.params[3].filter.list[.1]

  def updateMessages(self):
    """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
    parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
    if self.params[2].value == self.params[3].value:
        self.params[3].setErrorMessage("Values cannot be the same")
```

Answer (score 4):

Below is a `ToolValidator` class (in its entirety so it will make sense) where I needed not only for input datasets to have a spatial reference defined, BUT the datum could only be either WGS84 or NAD83. If validation failed, they got little messages informing them of the issues.

```
class ToolValidator:
  """Class for validating a tool's parameter values and controlling
  the behavior of the tool's dialog."""

  def __init__(self):
    """Setup arcpy and the list of tool parameters."""
    import arcpy
    self.params = arcpy.GetParameterInfo()
    self.p_in_kop_layer = self.params[1]
    self.p_in_kop_spatial_ref = self.params[2]
    self.p_in_infrastrx_layer = self.params[3]
    self.p_in_infrastrx_spatial_ref = self.params[4]
    self.acceptable_datums = ["D_North_American_1983", "D_WGS_1984"]    

  def initializeParameters(self):
    """Refine the properties of a tool's parameters.  This method is
    called when the tool is opened."""
    import ViesoreUtilities as v_util

    self.p_in_kop_spatial_ref.enabled = 0
    self.p_in_infrastrx_spatial_ref.enabled = 0
    self.p_in_infrastrx_layer.enabled = 1

    return

  def updateParameters(self):
    """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parmater
    has been changed."""
    if not self.p_in_kop_spatial_ref.value:
      self.p_in_kop_spatial_ref.enabled = 0
    if not self.p_in_infrastrx_spatial_ref.value:
      self.p_in_infrastrx_spatial_ref.enabled = 0

    if self.p_in_kop_layer.value:
      # Check to see if a valid spatial ref exists on the input layer
      sr = arcpy.Describe(self.p_in_kop_layer.value).spatialReference
      if sr.name == "Unknown":
        self.p_in_kop_spatial_ref.enabled = 1  

    if self.p_in_infrastrx_layer.value:
      sr2 = arcpy.Describe(self.p_in_infrastrx_layer.value).spatialReference
      if sr2.name == "Unknown":
        self.p_in_infrastrx_spatial_ref.enabled = 1

    return

  def updateMessages(self):
    """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
    parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
    # ########## KOP SR #############
    # Test to make sure input KOP layer has valid, acceptable datum
    if self.p_in_kop_layer.value:
      datum = self.get_datum(self.p_in_kop_layer.value)
      if datum not in self.acceptable_datums:
        self.p_in_kop_layer.setErrorMessage("Your datum " + datum + " is unacceptable."\
                                             "Please project your data into the "\
                                             "WGS84 or NAD83 datums via the Project "\
                                             "Tool before proceeding.")

      sr = arcpy.Describe(self.p_in_kop_layer.value).spatialReference
      if sr.name == "Unknown":    
        self.p_in_kop_layer.setWarningMessage("Your input KOP layer does not "\
                                              "have a spatial reference defined. "\
                                              "Please select one below.")
    # Test datum of SR OBJECT user selects for input KOP layer definition
    #   Has to be in WGS84 or NAD83 datums

    if self.p_in_kop_spatial_ref.value:
      datum = self.parse_datum(self.p_in_kop_spatial_ref.value)
      if datum not in self.acceptable_datums:
        self.p_in_kop_spatial_ref.setErrorMessage("Your datum " + datum + " is unacceptable. "\
                                                  "NAD83 and WGS84 are the only allowed "\
                                                  "datums.")
      else:
        self.p_in_kop_layer.clearMessage()

    # ########## INFRASTRUCTURE SR #############
    # Test to make sure input KOP layer has valid, acceptable datum
    if self.p_in_infrastrx_layer.value:
      datum = self.get_datum(self.p_in_infrastrx_layer.value)
      if datum not in self.acceptable_datums:
        self.p_in_infrastrx_layer.setErrorMessage("Your datum " + datum + " is unacceptable."\
                                             "Please project your data into the "\
                                             "WGS84 or NAD83 datums via the Project "\
                                             "Tool before proceeding.")

      sr = arcpy.Describe(self.p_in_infrastrx_layer.value).spatialReference
      if sr.name == "Unknown":    
        self.p_in_infrastrx_layer.setWarningMessage("Your input KOP layer does not "\
                                              "have a spatial reference defined. "\
                                              "Please select one below.")
    # Test datum of SR OBJECT user selects for input KOP layer definition
    #   Has to be in WGS84 or NAD83 datums

    if self.p_in_infrastrx_spatial_ref.value:
      datum = self.parse_datum(self.p_in_infrastrx_spatial_ref.value)
      if datum not in self.acceptable_datums:
        self.p_in_infrastrx_spatial_ref.setErrorMessage("Your datum " + datum + " is unacceptable. "\
                                                        "NAD83 and WGS84 are the only allowed "\
                                                        "datums.")
      else:
        self.p_in_infrastrx_layer.clearMessage()

    return

  def parse_datum(self, k):
      """"Parse out the datum info from a text prj string"""
      import re
      sr_string = k.exportToString()
      r1 = re.compile(r"DATUM\['(.*)',SPHEROID")
      if r1.findall(sr_string):
          datum = r1.findall(sr_string)[0]
      else:
          datum = "UNKNOWN" 
      return datum

  def get_datum(self, input_ds):
      """Get spatial reference of input raster, get string representation
         of SR, then parse out the datum. 

      """
      import re

      try:
          # Parse datum out of spatial reference object
          sr = arcpy.Describe(input_ds).spatialReference
          d = self.parse_datum(sr)
      except:
          d = self.parse_datum(input_ds)            

      return d
```